# Parse List from SOAP with Python and LXML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, soap, lxml

not having any success parsing a list from a SOAP response.
Here is my SOAP response:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <soap11env:Envelope xmlns:s1="my.models.com" xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="me.web.3.0.4">
        <soap11env:Body>
            <tns:resultsResponse>
                <tns:resultsResult>
                    <s1:FullResponse>
                        <s1:customer_id>12345</s1:customer_id>    
                    </s1:FullResponse>
                </tns:resultsResult>
                <tns:resultsResult>
                    <s1:FullResponse>
                        <s1:customer_id>123456</s1:customer_id>    
                    </s1:FullResponse>
                </tns:resultsResult>
            </tns:resultsResponse>
        </soap11env:Body>
    </soap11env:Envelope>
```

I need to retrieve each 'resultsResult', there should be a list of them.

My code so far:

```
doc = etree.XML(response.text.encode())
tree = etree.ElementTree(doc)
```

I'm not able to access the underlying data with my current code.
Any ideas how to get the list of 'resultsResult' items?

Comment: Your xml has only one ` <tns:resultsResult>` with content; the other is empty. What exactly is your expected output from the sample in the question?

Comment: I need to retrieve multiple 'resultsResult', ignore the empty one. I need to retrieve multiple of them.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, try:

```
target = doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="customer_id"]/text()')
target
```

In your sample xml, the output should be the following list:

```
['12345', '123456']
```

Comment: any reason you are not using the namespace variable, and is something supposed to follow 'target' on that last line?

Comment: @NightRider You're right! it's a copy-and-paste error! Edited it away; sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a common pitfall, which is that your XML elements are all in namespaces. In order to specify the namespaces, you should pass them in to the function as a dictionary, then write your xpath with the corresponding prefix you choose.

```
In [16]: NAMESPACES = {'foo': 'my.models.com', 'bar': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'baz': 'me.web.3.0.4'}

In [17]: results = tree.xpath('//baz:resultsResult//foo:customer_id', namespaces=NAMESPACES)

In [18]: results
Out[18]: 
[<Element {my.models.com}customer_id at 0x10e932140>,
 <Element {my.models.com}customer_id at 0x10f166240>]

In [19]: for result in results:
    ...:     print(result.text)
    ...: 
    ...: 
12345
123456

In [20]: for result in results:
    ...:     print(result.xpath('string(.)'))
    ...: 
    ...: 
12345
123456
```

(It would be clearer to use the original `s1`, `soap11env` and `tns` prefixes for these namespaces in your code, but `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are used here to demonstrate that the prefix is arbitrary and is not the namespace itself.)